# what is git branch name in jenkins pipeline when invoked by gitlab webhook

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, git-webhooks

I can invoke a simple Jenkins pipeline from gitlab merge requests using a webhook. Now I'd like to know what is the source branch to make the checkout against it. Example: if I push code to develop branch, in my pipeline script i'd checkout develop branch. Thanks.

```
node {
  stage('Build') {
    def mybranch = '?' // get branch name from gitlab webhook
    git branch: mybranch,
    credentialsId: 'mycredential',
    url: 'myurl'
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current branch name via `env.gitlabBranch`.

Reference: [gitlab-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#defined-variables)

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterize your pipeline and use the webhook payload data to fill in the branch value as described [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-hook-plugin#parameterized-projects).

Answer (score 1):

GitLab plugin creates a lot of useful environment variable. [You can see them in here.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) I think the one you need is `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`